# How to interact with alertdialog in Espresso?

Tags: testing, android-espresso, barista

I have a test in which I have a Alertdialog on which there is an "input" field and buttons "Cancel"(id is button2) and "Ok"(id is button1). First I have to enter the value "1234" in the field, and then click on the "Ok" button. But it doesn’t work for me, the test fails.

```
    onView(withId(R.id.input)).perform(typeText("1234"));
    closeSoftKeyboard();
    click(R.id.button1);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the the `isDialog()` [RootMatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/RootMatchers):

```
onView(allOf(
       isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.input)),
       isAssignableFrom(EditText.class)))
    .inRoot(isDialog())
    .perform(typeText("1234"))
    .perform(closeSoftKeyboard());
onView(withText("Ok"))
    .inRoot(isDialog())
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    .perform(click());
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Try using `withText` on the Ok button. See the updated answer

Comment: In the past, gives such an error "Cannot resolve method 'click()'"

Comment: Could it be that the `closeSoftKeyboard();` hides the dialog? Try without it or move it as an action of the input

Comment: Error performing 'type text(1234)' on view 'with id: by.belinvestbank.test:id/input'.

Comment: Are you using TextInputLayout? Try checking for a descendant of type `EditText`. See the updated answer

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you very much) Only when you click on the "Ok" button it gives an error "Cannot resolve method 'click()'". Therefore, instead of clicking on this button from your example, I used Barista -BaristaDialogActions.clickDialogPositiveButton();